# Filtering Pivot Table Based on Two Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to filter a pivot table based on the values in two different cells.
Each cell will filter a different field in the pivot table.

I know how to filter my pivot table based on the value in one cell.
However, I do not know how to add a second filter.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xptable As PivotTable
    Dim xpfile As PivotField
    Dim xstr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xptable = Worksheets("Sheet11").PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    Set xpfile = xptable.PivotFields("FilterField")
    xstr = target.Text
    xpfile.ClearAllFilters
    xpfile.CurrentPage = xstr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you already have 2 different filters above your pivot table?

Comment: I do.  I just don't want to use the filter.  I need the table to update automatically when the values are plugged into the cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pivot table (`Dim xptable As PivotTable`) can either either be addressed by its name or its number on its worksheet, e. g.

```
Set xptable = Worksheets("Given Name of Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
Set xptable = Worksheets("Given Name of Sheet3").PivotTables(1)
Set xptable = Sheet3.PivotTables(1) ' or just use codename of Sheet3
```

Your filter field (`Dim xpfile As PivotField`) can be addressed either as `PivotField` or as `PageField`. This is almost the same, but I suggest the latter for better identification. e. g.

```
Set xpfile = xptable.PivotFields("MyFirstFilterFieldName")
Set xpfile = xptable.PageFields("MyFirstFilterFieldName")
Set xpfile = xptable.PageFields(1)
```

To filter a single entry, set the pagefield's `CurrentPage` to a caption of a valid `PivotItem`. You have to ensure by a loop over all its `PivotItems`, that the caption exists (otherwise you'll get an error).

```
Dim xpitem As PivotItem
With xpfile
    .ClearAllFilters
    For Each xpitem In .PivotItems
        If xpitem.Caption = ... Then
            .CurrentPage = ...
            Exit For
        End If
    Next xpitem
```

---

If you want to automate this by every change of a specific cell, place following code in the **code module** of that worksheet, **where your cell input is** (not where the pivot table is).

`Target` represents the cell range, where something was changed. As it could be much larger (e. g. someone copied a large range from clipboard to the sheet), you have to check by `Intersect`, if your cell is changed and then use the individual cell's value.

Within the worksheet's code module you reference the corresponding worksheet by `Me`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xptable As PivotTable
    Dim xpfile As PivotField
    Dim xpitem As PivotItem

    Set xptable = Sheet3.PivotTables("PivotTable3")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Set xpfile = xptable.PageFields(1)
        With xpfile
            .ClearAllFilters
            For Each xpitem In .PivotItems
                If xpitem.Caption = Me.Range("A1").Value Then
                    .CurrentPage = Me.Range("A1").Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next xpitem
        End With

    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A2")) Is Nothing Then
        ' like above
    End If
End Sub
```

---

If you need one filter with *multiple* items, then you have to `EnableMultiplePageItems` and hide all unwanted pivotitems - but you have to assure, that always *at least one pivotitem* remains visible, e. g.

```
Dim AtLeastOneVisible As Boolean
With myPivotTable.PageFields(1)
    .ClearAllFilters
    .EnableMultiplePageItems = True

    AtLeastOneVisible = False
    For Each myPivotItem In .PivotItems
        If myPivotItem .Caption = ... Or myPivotItem .Caption = ... Then
            AtLeastOneVisible = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next myPivotItem

    If AtLeastOneVisible Then
        For Each myPivotItem In .PivotItems
            If myPivotItem .Caption <> ... And myPivotItem .Caption <> ... Then
                pi.Visible = False
            End If
        Next myPivotItem 
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write that code.  I really appreciate it.  

This is what I have so far:

Comment: Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: Okay I just have one last question.  In my first query I used  xstr = target.Text.  In my second one I set xstr = Range("H6") xstr2 = Range("H7") .  Those are the two cells where the data will be entered.  

Will it basically do the same thing.  BTW, this is completely new to me, so I have to ask a lot of questions.  SOrry

Comment: Okay, I marked your answer as accepted and i deleted my other comment.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can I ask you another question?

Comment: It's related to my question above.  The user will input data on a different spreadsheet, and I need the pivot table to filter based on that value.

Comment: Here is what I have now

`
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xptable As PivotTable
    Dim xpfile As PivotField
    Dim xstr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    If Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Other").Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xptable = Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    Set xpfile = xptable.PivotFields("Filter")
    xstr = Worksheets("Other").Range("A1")
    xpfile.ClearAllFilters
    xpfile.CurrentPage = xstr
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
`

Comment: In this case, I am only filtering on one field

Comment: I rewrote my answer to get many more questions answered and hope you get everything running.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's working just the way I need it to.